# How to paste columns using different connectors

Tags: r

For example,

```
df<-data.frame(chr=c(3,4,5),
 start=c(11,12,13),
 end=c(21,22,23))
df
  chr start end
1   3    11  21
2   4    12  22
3   5    13  23
```

My question is to paste the three columns using ":" and "-" such that a desired output for `df$anno` would be:

```
df
  chr start end    anno
1   3    11  21 3:11-21
2   4    12  22 4:12-22
3   5    13  23 5:13-23
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I would use `sprintf`:

```
df <- within(df, anno <- sprintf("%d:%d-%d", chr, start, end))

#  chr start end    anno
#1   3    11  21 3:11-21
#2   4    12  22 4:12-22
#3   5    13  23 5:13-23
```

Comment: That's elegant. Thanks

Answer (score 5):

`paste` is vectorized.  So, we can directly paste the columns with the specified delimiters in between

```
df$anno <- with(df, paste0(chr, ":", start, "-", end))
df$anno
#[1] "3:11-21" "4:12-22" "5:13-23"
```

---

Or using `str_c`

```
library(tidyverse)
df %>%
    mutate(anno = str_c(chr, ":", start, "-", end))
```

Answer (score 2):

Also you can do by using much simpler way:

```
a$anno<-paste(paste(a$chr, a$start, sep = ":"), a$end, sep = "-")
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is another one for fun,

```
sub('-', ':', do.call(paste, c(df, sep = '-')))
#[1] "3:11-21" "4:12-22" "5:13-23"
```

Answer (score 1):

The package `glue` always helps a lot for readability :

```
library(glue)
transform(df, anno = glue("{chr}:{start}-{end}"))
#   chr start end    anno
# 1   3    11  21 3:11-21
# 2   4    12  22 4:12-22
# 3   5    13  23 5:13-23
```